# Recursive fill overflows

Tags: java, recursion

Was looking at an SO question where I suggested filling a grid of nodes recursively and I thought I should try the code for myself, the following keeps overflowing

```
public class Node {

private Node left;
private Node right;
private Node up;
private Node down;
private int x;
private int y;

public Node(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public static void buildGrid(Node node) {
    fill(node);
}

private static void fill(Node node) {
    fillLeft(node);
    fillRight(node);
}

private static void fillRight(Node node) {
    if (node.right != null || node.x > 10)
        return;

    node.right = new Node(node.x + 1, node.y);
    fill(node.right);
}

private static void fillLeft(Node node) {
    if (node.left != null || node.x <= 0)
        return;

    node.left = new Node(node.x - 1, node.y);
    fill(node.left);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node node = new Node(5, 5);
    buildGrid(node);
}
```

It is so late I might have missed the very obvious but why would this overflow? The first time `fillLeft` returns with `fill(node.left)` the second call to `fillLeft(node.left)` should immediately return since `node.left.right != null`. The same for `fillRight`, can't figure out what is wrong here.

Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at Node.<init>(Node.java:16)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:42)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
at Node.fill(Node.java:26)
at Node.fillRight(Node.java:35)
at Node.fill(Node.java:27)
at Node.fillLeft(Node.java:43)
```

Comment: What's the exact exception trace you are getting? It may be that java's implicit stack is the one that overflows due to all the recursion.

Comment: Please show your `Node` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not properly creating the links between new nodes. You want:

```
private static void fillRight(Node node) {
    if (node.right != null || node.x > 10)
        return;

    node.right = new Node(node.x + 1, node.y);
    node.right.left = node; // CURRENT NODE IS LEFT OF NEW NODE!
    fill(node.right);
}

private static void fillLeft(Node node) {
    if (node.left != null || node.x <= 0)
        return;

    node.left = new Node(node.x - 1, node.y);
    node.left.right = node; // CURRENT NODE IS RIGHT OF NEW NODE!
    fill(node.left);
}
```

If you print out the coordinates of the current node being filled you can see it goes left and oscillates because the link "back" is always `null`. Add this to the beginning of `fill()` to see what is happening:

```
private static void fill(Node node) {
    System.out.println("filling node " + node.x + " " + node.y + 
                       " " + node.left + " " + node.right); 
    ...
```

Secondly: Recursive grid filling gets messy fast and can easily lead to a high recursive depth and a quick overflow. With these types of things you are better off using a queue than doing it recursively.

Comment: That is true but it is more of a curiosity thing, I wouldn't dream of doing it like this in a real setting but it is curious that it overflows with just 10 Nodes along x, I omitted filling along y because it overflows with just one dimension.

Comment: @arynaq You didn't set up the bidirectional links between nodes completely. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Of course, seems so silly now, this is what I get for coding at 06:21, thank you, I would not be able to sleep like this was driving me mad.

Answer (score 1):

Call `fillRight()` from  `fillRight()` and likewise for left.

Currently it is making a new node, then calling `fill()` on this node, which has null left/right pointers...

Answer (score 1):

Your fillLeft and fillRight will never hit the conditions node.left != null and the node.right != null which would have stopped the recursion.

Looks like x and y are your keys and you will have to store them based on x and y somewhere and retrieve them back if they are already created instead of calling a new Node always.